# Android Studio add .jar files with gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to work on an Android application with Android Studio. Therefore I set up everything accordingly (as far as I know).

My build.gardle (in CampusApp folder) looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}
```

**When I try to Run:**

```
./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build
```

**it gives me many errors that say**

"*error: package XXXX does not exist*"

```
/Users/foo/git/CampusAppProject/CampusApp/src/main/java/de/unitrier/caching/DiskLruImageCache.java:7: error: package com.android.volley.toolbox does not exist
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
[...]
100 errors 
:CampusApp:compileDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CampusApp:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

My Workspace dir looks like:

[image]

Any Idea?

[edit]
Its not only volley that is not found. Its seems to be all those jar files that are in the lib folder

Comment: Do you have some JAR'd version of Volley in `libs/`? Also, why do you have two copies of `com.android.support:support-v4`?

Comment: First: Yes I do. Second: Ok thats a thing. I solve that - should be the play lib

Comment: fixed that and added some more error output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the libs folder were in the wrong folder. Should be in the / folder.